# How to check for a column data and extract data on the same row? CSV on Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am currently using Ruby for a CSV file and I am trying to print a column data given a condition.

```
Severity  Level
Least       1
Average     2
Normal      3
High        4
Severe      5

require "csv"
CSV.foreach('csvread.csv', :headers=>true) do |row|
  if (row[1] == 2) 
    puts row.inspect
  end
end
```

How do I select the `Level` column and print out the severity?

CSV file structure:

```
Severity;Level
Least;1
Average;2
Normal;3
High;4
Severe;5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access to Security and Level, and any other value you define in your header as `object['header']`.

In this case the object is each row for the iteration, and the values are Severity and Level, so:

```
require 'csv'

file = '/path_to_data/data.csv'
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true, col_sep: ';') do |row|
  p [row['Severity'], row['Level']]
end

# ["Least", "1"]
# ["Average", "2"]
# ["Normal", "3"]
# ["High", "4"]
# ["Severe", "5"]
```